# Labelling of a 2n-cycle with alternating coloured vertices in a specified fashion

Tags: co.combinatorics

Take a 2n-cycle, colouring the vertices alternately blue and red.  For which n can we label the vertices 1 to 2n in such a way that the sum of the label of each blue vertex together with its two red neighbours is the same for every blue vertex?

Comment: Have you done any calculations, gotten any partial answers?

Comment: I'll admit this is a minor re-formulation of a problem that I saw set for my 8-year old grandson.   And I haven't got far: n=2 obviously has no solution but there are solutions for n = 3 and 4.  For n = 3 (and maybe for 4) the solution is unique up to orientation.  I have found a few features of solutions, but it's all pretty rudimentary. (So the editors might tell me off - still, it looks interesting enough.)

Comment: Well, here's a solution for $n=5$, starting with red: $1,10,3,6,5,7,2,8,4,9,1$.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique up to orientation"? For n=3 there are solutions which require more than permutation to consider part of a single equivalence class: e.g. $1, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5$ (where the reds are $1,2,3$) and $2,5,4,1,6,3$ (where the reds are $2,4,6$).

Comment: To judge by the example given in [OEIS A145692](http://oeis.org/A145692), these are precisely the "vertex-magic total labelings on cycle C_n" of Andrew Baker and Joe Sawada, *Magic Labelings on Cycles and Wheels*, Lecture Notes in Computer Science 5165 (Combinatorial Optimization and Applications. Second International Conference, COCOA 2008), pp. 361-373.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there is a simple construction for odd $n=2k+1$'s. The construction is
$$k+1,4k+2,1,4k+1,k+2,4k,2,4k-1,\dots,2k,2k+4,k,2k+3,2k+1,2k+2$$
the smaller numbers are red, the larger are blue. The sum of label of each  blue vertex together with its two red neighbors is the same $5k+4$.

update:

Well, there is a not-that simple construction for evenly even $n=4k$. The construction for the red ones are:

$$1,6k,2,2k+2,3,2k+3,\dots ,k,3k,k+1,k+2,3k+1,k+3,3k+2,\dots,2k,4k-1,2k+1$$

(especially when $k=1$ the red ones are $1,6,2,3$)

These appears $1$ to $4k-1$ and a strange $6k$

The blue ones (in between) are
$$4k+1,4k,8k-2,8k-3,\dots 6k+2,6k+1,8k-1,6k-1,6k-2\dots,4k+2,8k$$

And the sum is $10k+2$.

update2:

Well, there is a really not-that simple construction for oddly even $n=4k+2$. The construction for the red ones are:

$$1,6k+3,2,2k+2,3,2k+3,\dots ,k,3k,k+1,k+2,3k+1,3k+2,k+3,\dots,4k,2k+1,4k+1$$

(especially when $k=1$ the red ones are $1,9,2,3,4,5$)

These appears $1$ to $4k+1$ and a strange $6k+3$

The blue ones (in between) are
$$4k+3,4k+2,8k+3,8k+2,\dots ,6k+7,6k+6,8k+4,6k+4,4k+4,6k+2,\dots,4k+6,4k+5,6k+5$$

And the sum is $10k+7$.

So, we proved that all the $n\ge 3$we can label in the way.

Comment: Is this right?  For the n = 4k case, if k = 1 then 2n = 8.  You say the blues are labelled 1,6,2,3.  Then the reds are then labelled (in some order) 4,5,7, and 8  and you say the  common RBR sum is 10k + 2 = 12.  However the sum of the two reds adjacent to the blue 6 is 12 - 6 = 6, which is an impossible sum from 4, 5, 7, and 8.

Comment: @PeterHiggins Consider 1 (5) 6 (4) 2 (7) 3 (8) 1. I may have a typo for reversing understanding red and blue but it is minor. I might not remember really clearly. This is the post long ago. Now I have fixed that.

Comment: OK, thanks for clearing that up;  'red' needs to change to 'blue' as well,  halfway down the  n = 4k case.

Comment: @PeterHiggins okay, I have fixed that

Comment: I have written this up.  If you would like to read these notes, please contact me at peteh@essex.ac.uk.